# How we can use topas as scripting

Tags: bash, aix

How we can fetch all data of topas in bash script?
I Tried
topas -bnl  not working properly.
Also tried using
-head command

Comment: The data displayed by `topas` is very diverse, what kind of data you want to capture. Have you check `nmon`?

Comment: Hello Romeo,  We Dont have permission to install nmon ..I wanna check %use CPU

Comment: I remember hearing that topas and nmon were going to be merged; it may have happened already. If so, nmon has CLI options for creating non-interactive ("record") mode output: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.3?topic=n-nmon-command. Indeed, on a sample system, /usr/bin/nmon is a shell script that calls topas_nmon, which is hard-linked to the topas binary.

Answer (score 0):

With command:

```
(sleep 3; echo q) | topas -p
```

This will exec `topas` to get only CPU information. BTW think about using `ps` command too.

Comment: topas -P only provide cpu  usage by individual Procees

Comment: small `-p` , not caps